# Understand extent with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some trouble with the use of d3js and dates:

This is some data, an array of objects with a weight and a date

```
var weights = [{"atdate":"2013-09-07","weight":"82","comment":"Reprise !"},
{"atdate":"2013-09-10","weight":"81.3","comment":""},
{"atdate":"2013-09-15","weight":"80.8","comment":""},
{"atdate":"2013-09-16","weight":"80.8","comment":""},
{"atdate":"2013-09-17","weight":"80.3","comment":""},
{"atdate":"2013-09-18","weight":"81.2","comment":""},
{"atdate":"2013-09-19","weight":"80.9","comment":""},
{"atdate":"2013-09-20","weight":"80.7","comment":""},
{"atdate":"2013-09-21","weight":"81","comment":""},
{"atdate":"2013-09-22","weight":"80.8","comment":""}];
```

You can see that the minimum date is 2013-09-07 and the maximum is 2013-09-22

Now, i send this data to a function

```
function draw_spline (_weights) {

    var parse_date = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d').parse;
    var weights = _weights.map(function(w) {
        w.atdate = parse_date(w.atdate);
        w.weight = parseFloat(w.weight);
        return w;
    })

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0,width]);

    var boundaries_dates = d3.extent(weights, function(d){return d.atdate});
    console.log('boundaries_dates',boundaries_dates);
    x.domain(boundaries_dates);
    console.log('domain extent',x.domain());

    ...
```

I construct real date objects with the use of parse_date. Here is the output of the console :

```
boundaries_dates, Array [
    Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 , 
    Sun Sep 22 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 ]
domain extent, Array [
    Sat Sep 07 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 , 
    Sun Sep 22 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 ]
```

As you can see, the extent is wrong, instead of 2013-09-07 i have today. I would like to have the minimum date.

What bugs me is that if i send the extent to a scale domain, the scale.domain() returns the values i want. (So there is a way to get what i want, but it feels wrong).

So,

How to have the correct extent with d3.extent() ?

How does the scale to get the right first date from an array which does not contain it ?

Thank you

Comment: Works for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/Cj6Yy/

Comment: works for me too in jsfiddle ... perhaps something bugs my console output ...

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a typo somewhere or scoping issues.